# Auto-refresh image gallery?

Tags: jquery, django, photologue

I was thinking of using django-photologue for my gallery, but I'd like it to have capability to automatically show newly uploaded images at, for example, top. Is that possible with photologue or should I  use some other gallery?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hedde [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836406/auto-refresh-image-gallery#comment19043678_13836406) in the comments, you should be able to override django-photologue's templates as [mentioned](http://django-photologue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/essentials/installation.html#instant-photo-gallery) in its documentation and use ajax requests to the server to determine whether a new image is available.

Of course, django-photologue isn't necessary for this functionality, but it should at least get you started.